# parser error in aspx page(.net 2.0) after converting from website to web application

Tags: .net, parsing, asp.net

I have a website I recently converted from website to web application Project . When I compile It compiles Successfuly but when I  run the code I get this error

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'DApplause.Logon'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind ="Logon.aspx.vb"  inherits="DApplause.Logon"%>
Line 2:  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
Line 3:  <HTML>


Source File: /Shared/LogOn.aspx    Line: 1 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053
```

I have tried to resolve this error for like a day now.

I am currently running with the internal web server of VS 2005 sp1. I have the Sain.dll in my bin folder cuase the assembly name use is sain and Root Namespace is DApplause . Please I need urgent help.

Answer (score 0):

Your inherits attribute is looking for a class called "Logon" in the namespace "DApplause".

What namespace are your ASPX pages in?

Can you please provide the namespace and class definition for Logon.aspx?

It should look like this:

```
namespace DApplause
{
     public partial class Logon
     {
```

If it doesnt, you need to change your inherits attribute.